# How to open exodus wallet exodus-linux-x64-19.10.18 on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, chrome

Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2019.4
Codename:   kali-rolling

I am tring to update my exodus wallet and this version has a chrome-sandbox file in it. It seems that I need to use a sandbox but the app needs special permission. Suid 0 that is root.

On google the only problem that seems the same is with chrome browser, but that can be opened with argument --no-sandbox. I understand that this app needs special permission...

The first error is this:

[9017:1024/114423.197771:FATAL:atom_main_delegate.cc(194)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Trace/breakpoint trap

With chrome-sandbox

The setuid sandbox provides API version 1, but you need 0
Please read https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md.
THE SECOND

I tried opening in another user that is not root...but the same. Chromium browser is working...jut saying, I dont know if it is relevant...I have a lot to learn.   If anybody has encountered this same issue or knows from where to tackle the problem, I would be gratefuul..............I thing I need to build Chromium